# Best efficient way to make a fulltext search in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have 3 tables, and I want to make a query for a search term textbox. My query currently looks something like this:

```
SELECT Artist.* FROM Artist, Band, Instrument WHERE MATCH (Artist.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Band.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Instrument.name, Instrument.description) AGAINST ('mysearchterm');
```

This query is taking too much time to get executed. Is there any way to improve this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would move to a fulltext search engine instead of trying to optimize this.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/about.html

Comment: +1 for using an external engine, be it Sphinx or anything else (Lucene ? there are commercial tools too, btw)

Answer (score 4):

MYSQL has full text search support that will give much better performance.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

However, I would recommend using a system designed for fulltext search if you intend to place any significant load on your application.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I wish I could choose more than one correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late follow-up, but aren't you doing a Cartesian join against those three tables?

```
SELECT Artist.* FROM Artist, Band, Instrument WHERE MATCH (Artist.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Band.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Instrument.name, Instrument.description) AGAINST ('mysearchterm');
```

Assuming a database with 100 bands, 10 instruments, and 500 artists you're searching through 500,000 rows.

I would expect to see something like assuming you have a database where Artist belongs to one band and plays one instrument:

```
SELECT Artist.* FROM Artist, Band, Instrument WHERE Artist.band_id = Band.id and Artist.instrument_id = Instrument.id and (MATCH (Artist.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Band.name) AGAINST ('mysearchterm') OR MATCH (Instrument.name, Instrument.description) AGAINST ('mysearchterm'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like the following, which is not a fulltext search?

```
SELECT Artist.* FROM Artist, Band, Instrument WHERE Artist.name LIKE '%mysearchterm%'...
```

Or (my preference):

```
SELECT Artist.* FROM Artist, Band, Instrument WHERE Artist.name REGEXP '<regexp here>'...
```