# Solr Search Field Best Practices

Tags: search, solr, enterprise

I'm using solr for an enterprise application. So far it works well, as I am using a ngram field to search against. It works correctly for partial queries (match against indexed ngrams). But the problem I have is, how to enforce exact query matches?. For an example the query "Test 1" should match exactly the same text as it is when the user enter it with double quotation marks. Currently Since I have used some tokenizers and filters, the double quotation marks get filtered out, there's no difference in the queries `"test 1", "tEst 1" or "TEST 1"` (that is because of the analyzer chain I use, but it is needed to work with ngrams and partial search).

Currently I'm searching against a ngram query field. In order to enforce exact query match, what should I do? what is the best practice?. currently what I think is to identify the double quotation marks from client side and change the query field to the original field (with out ngrams). But I feel like there should be a better way of doing this, since the problem I have is generic and `solr` is a complete enterprise level search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another `field` for it and add `string` as the `fieldType` for the same and index it with same.

When you want to perform the exact match you can query on the above field.

And when you want to perform partial search ..you can query to the earlier field which is indexed by ngram.

OR.. Here is another way you can try.

You have defined the current field type using the ngram. In that while indexing you can define the ngram tokenizer and for the query you mention keywordTokenizer and lowercase filter factory only.

While indexing the text will be tokenized and while performing the query it will not.

Comment: So you mean, I should I dentify the double quotations from the client side and change the query field according to that?. I thought about this, but Isn't this a generic problem that solr may have solved it already ? I was thinking I may be reinventing the wheel

Comment: But the question is, How I can handle when the user deliberately input the query with double quotations?. In your approach we'll have to use an mechanism to normalize the index and query both, then there's no meaning of the double quotations. It should match case sensitive fields also. I found the pf field in edismax parser .. i'm having a look at it :)

Comment: I think this is not supported by solr : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6842